# TimeZone change to UTC while updating the Appointment

Tags: sharepoint-2010, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I am using EWS 1.2 to send appointments. On creating new Appointments, TimeZone is showing properly on notification mail, but on updating the same appointment, it's TimeZone reset to UTC.

Could anyone help me to fix this issue?

Here is sample code to replicate the issue:

```cs
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time"));
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("ews_calendar", PASSWORD, "acme");
service.Url = new Uri("https://acme.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");

Appointment newAppointment = new Appointment(service);
newAppointment.Subject = "Test Subject";
newAppointment.Body = "Test Body";
newAppointment.Start = new DateTime(2012, 03, 27, 17, 00, 0);
newAppointment.End = newAppointment.Start.AddMinutes(30);
newAppointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("tin.tin@acme.com");

//Attendees get notification mail for this appointment using (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada) timezone
//Here is the notification content received by attendees:
//When: Tuesday, March 27, 2012 5:00 PM-5:30 PM. (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
newAppointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);

// Pull existing appointment
string itemId = newAppointment.Id.ToString();

Appointment existingAppointment = Appointment.Bind(service, new ItemId(itemId));

//Attendees get notification mail for this appointment using UTC timezone
//Here is the notification content received by attendees:
//When: Tuesday, March 27, 2012 11:00 PM-11:30 PM. UTC
existingAppointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to set `AppointmentSchema.StartTimeZone` and bind it as part of the properties object when you bind `existingAppointment`, as [illustrated here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332363%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx):

```
// Get an existing calendar item, requesting the Id, Start, and 
//  StartTimeZone properties.
PropertySet props = new PropertySet(
      AppointmentSchema.Id, 
      AppointmentSchema.Start, 
      AppointmentSchema.StartTimeZone);
Appointment appt = Appointment.Bind(service, new ItemId("AQMkA="), props);
```

It seems the default bound time zone is UTC.

Comment: I set AppointmentSchema.StartTimeZone as you suggested but still EWS sending notification mail in UTC timezone.

Comment: @FirozAnsari Understood. Likewise, what happens when you bind it for `newAppointment` in your code above? The [linked article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332363(v=exchg.140).aspx) seems to cover many cases for this exact issue and feature in EWS for Exchange 2010. Unless you can gather more information on the properties of your server, I believe poking at the connection with a well-defined timezone is the most appropriate course of action.

Comment: Thanks MrGomez. With newAppointment, notification timezone is proper. My only problem is with updating existing appointments. I looked into this article and this article explains how to convert start & end date to specific timezone. I am not sure how I can convert the dates while calling existingAppointment.Update. Thank you once again for your help.

Comment: @FirozAnsari: Do you always want the same time zone? If so, have you tried just explicitly setting it on the one you're updating? Maybe it's not being fetched properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try out using an other overload of `Bind()` which allows explicitly specifying which properties to load. Basically specify all `TimeZone` specific property definition in third parameter of `Bind()`, regarding MSDN's paper [To change the time zone for an appointment without changing the start time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633623%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx):

> Bind to the existing appointment by using its unique identifier. The
>   following code shows how to bind to an existing appointment, provide
>   it with connection configuration information by using an
>   ExchangeService object named service, and request a specific subset of
>   properties, including the DateTime properties and the time zone
>   properties. The ItemId has been shortened to preserve readability. For
>   the purpose of this example, assume that the service object is scoped
>   to the Pacific Standard Time (PST) time zone.

```cs
var appt = Appointment.Bind(
            service, 
            new ItemId(itemId), 
            new PropertySet(
                  BasePropertySet.IdOnly, 
                  AppointmentSchema.Start, 
                  AppointmentSchema.ReminderDueBy, 
                  AppointmentSchema.End, 
                  AppointmentSchema.StartTimeZone, 
                  AppointmentSchema.EndTimeZone, 
                  AppointmentSchema.TimeZone)); 

appt.StartTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Coordinated Universal Time");
appt.EndTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Coordinated Universal Time");

appt.Update(
        ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, 
        SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);

appt.Load(new PropertySet(
                   BasePropertySet.IdOnly, 
                   AppointmentSchema.Start,              
                   AppointmentSchema.ReminderDueBy, 
                   AppointmentSchema.End, 
                   AppointmentSchema.StartTimeZone, 
                   AppointmentSchema.EndTimeZone, 
                   AppointmentSchema.TimeZone));
```

Also below you can find useful MSDN how-tos:

- Your case: [Updating the time zone for items by using the EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633623%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)
- [Getting time zone definitions by using the EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633685%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)
- [Specifying the time zone when creating items by using the EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633707%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)
- [Specifying the time zone when retrieving items by using the EWS Managed API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633686%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)