# How to specify EDT (daylight saving time) to Exchange Web Services (XML not managed)?

Tags: timezone, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

The article here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb738399(v=exchg.80).aspx

in the section "Use Registry Key Names for TimeZoneNames", tells me that when I can create a calendar item in Exchange, I can pass it the name of a timezone. This is sort-of working, but how do I name "Eastern Daylight Time"?

Only 'US Eastern Standard Time' is accepted as valid. In works in that I schedule something for say 14:00, when it displays in my Google calendar I see it is displaying at 15:00 EDT, so it used the EST timezone I passed in. Problem is that it sends out reminder emails with the time displayed in "US Eastern Standard Time".

```
When: Friday, August 30, 2013 2:00 PM-3:00 PM. US Eastern Standard Time
... rest of email ...
```

I don't want that text like that. It should say "US Eastern Daylight Time" or something like that.

The soap request contains XML like:

```
<t:CalendarItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">  
    ...
    <Start>2013-08-30T14:00:00</Start>     
    <t:MeetingTimeZone TimeZoneName="US Eastern Standard Time"></t:MeetingTimeZone>
<t:CalendarItem>
```

This is Exchange Server 2007, SP1.

Here is an image of what the email looks like, in Gmail. (The times are bit different from my above example, sorry).  The appointment time is correct, but it in the email body it calls it "Eastern Standard Time", which is not right -- it should be "Eastern Daylight Time" or something like that.  (Note that line is part of the email body generated by the Exchange Server, it is not something made up by Gmail.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Time Zone key you're looking for is exactly: `"Eastern Standard Time"`.  This covers the US Eastern time zone, inclusive of *both* Eastern Standard Time and Eastern Daylight Time.  It has a display name of `"(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)"`.

This is actually one of the examples I call out in the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) - which you should read if you haven't already.

The other key you found `"US Eastern Standard Time"` is actually for the zone with the display name of `"(UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)"` - which is segregated for historical reasons and is now obsolete.  (See the Wikipedia entry on [Time in Indiana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Indiana), and [Microsoft's KB article on this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/915577) if you are interested in why.)

If you look in the Windows Registry at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`, you will see the valid keys.  In each key, you will see the `Display` name that corresponds to each.  This explains how they appear when you change your time zone in Windows.

With regards to Exchange Web Services, in [the article you mentioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/bb738399.aspx), it does talk about how you can use the key name.  But it also talks about how you can pass much more information in the `MeetingTimeZone` element and use a display name instead.

If interoperability with Google Calendar (and others) is important, you might consider passing the IANA time zone name in the `TimeZoneName` attribute - in this case it would be `America/New_York`.  You would still need to provide the `<BaseOffset>`, `<Standard>`, and `<Daylight>` elements, so that it will work right on Windows.  See the `MeetingTimeZone` section in that article.

I should state that I haven't *tried* this approach myself, but it appears from the documentation that if you provide those elements that the `TimeZoneName` becomes less important to Windows but would still get passed along.

You should certainly be able to pass it using Microsoft's approach:

```xml
<MeetingTimeZone TimeZoneName="(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)">
  <BaseOffset>P0DT5H0M0.0S</BaseOffset>
  <Standard>
    <Offset>P0DT0H0M0.0S</Offset>
    <RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
      <DaysOfWeek>Sunday</DaysOfWeek>
      <DayOfWeekIndex>First</DayOfWeekIndex>
      <Month>November</Month>
    </RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
    <Time>02:00:00.0000000</Time>
  </Standard>
  <Daylight>
    <Offset>-P0DT1H0M0.0S</Offset>
    <RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
      <DaysOfWeek>Sunday</DaysOfWeek>
      <DayOfWeekIndex>Second</DayOfWeekIndex>
      <Month>March</Month>
    </RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
    <Time>02:00:00.0000000</Time>
  </Daylight>
</MeetingTimeZone>
```

What I'm suggesting is that you tweak it slightly by passing the IANA zone name instead and see if it behaves properly with Gmail and Google Calendar:

```xml
<MeetingTimeZone TimeZoneName="America/New_York">
  <BaseOffset>P0DT5H0M0.0S</BaseOffset>
  <Standard>
    <Offset>P0DT0H0M0.0S</Offset>
    <RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
      <DaysOfWeek>Sunday</DaysOfWeek>
      <DayOfWeekIndex>First</DayOfWeekIndex>
      <Month>November</Month>
    </RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
    <Time>02:00:00.0000000</Time>
  </Standard>
  <Daylight>
    <Offset>-P0DT1H0M0.0S</Offset>
    <RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
      <DaysOfWeek>Sunday</DaysOfWeek>
      <DayOfWeekIndex>Second</DayOfWeekIndex>
      <Month>March</Month>
    </RelativeYearlyRecurrence>
    <Time>02:00:00.0000000</Time>
  </Daylight>
</MeetingTimeZone>
```

Comment: Okay, I sent "Eastern Standard Time" for the TimeZoneName, but it still behaves badly. I've added an image to my question. Do you see my problem? Why is it displaying "Eastern Standard Time" in the email. It shouldn't say that when it's in daylight savings time, no?

Comment: This is an unfortunate side-effect of Microsoft having their own time zone database.  Google could try to detect this behavior and work around it, but that's probably not going to happen.  Give the other approach a try.  Give me a minute and I'll update the answer with all of the parameters you need.

Comment: Thank you.  That last line that says "Eastern Standard Time" is not Google, it's part of the email body text generated by the exchange server.  Google is correctly displaying "EDT".

Comment: See if that update fixes it for you.  At minimum, by passing the expanded form, you can probably put whatever you like in the `TimeZoneName` attribute.  Hopefully, if you pass the IANA zone key, it will be used on the other end.

Comment: Also, understand that there is translation going on.  You are interacting with Exchange Web Services, but ultimately Google probably receives an ical attachment.  So if that is your main area of concern, you might want to consider crafting your own ical instead of using EWS.  At least you won't be relying on Exchange to translate for you.

Comment: It works when I pass the full timezone info like that. Then I can give it any name I want.  Only one problem remains (grr). When I send `<DeleteItem>` and the server sends out cancellation emails, it writes the cancelled meeting time in the email, in GMT, without labeling it. Unbelievable. So the previous emails (good) say something like "1:00 PM Eastern Time" and then it cancels a meeting at "5:00 PM", which will confuse people. The <DeleteItem> element uses only IDs, and has no place for a timezone spec.  Any ideas on this last part?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough direct experience with EWS.  Perhaps someone else does.  Maybe a new question is in order.