# EWS GetUserAvailabilityRequest from javascript - How to set timezone information

Tags: javascript, timezone, exchangewebservices

Though it isn't clear in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa563800%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), it seems obvious that this chunk of the soap request is to be populated with data pertaining to the timezone of the device that the web client is running on. I'm making this assumption because most docs describe how to get this information from the Windows registry. However, that isn't going to work for a multi-platform web client.

Is my assumption correct that this timezone data pertains to the client OS?

If so, it's easy to get the current timezone offset (Bias) in JavaScript.

What about the rest of the data populating the elements to do with StandardTime and DaylightTime?

e.g.

```
 <SerializableTimeZone xmlns=".../types">
  <Bias>-600</Bias>
  <StandardTime>
    <Bias>0</Bias>
    <Time>03:00:00</Time>
    <DayOrder>5</DayOrder>
    <Month>3</Month>
    <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
  </StandardTime>
  <DaylightTime>
    <Bias>-60</Bias>
    <Time>02:00:00</Time>
    <DayOrder>5</DayOrder>
    <Month>10</Month>
    <DayOfWeek>Sunday</DayOfWeek>
  </DaylightTime>
</SerializableTimeZone>
```

Comment: I wish I knew how to improve this question and avoid the -1.

Comment: have you looked at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18366172/5884960)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used TimezoneJs to help with getting all timezone data.  TimezoneJs returns Olson (IANA) style timezone names, but the EWS soap request requires a Microsoft-style timezone name.  To help with that, I used the xml available from unicode.org to create a helper utility that maps IANA timezone names to MS-style timezone names.

You can get the xml here: http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/
The interesting files: metazones.xml and WindowsZones.xml